# Tracing and Binary Search

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

Currently in my second year of computer science, and we have just began our data structures & algorithms class.

One of our tutorials contains a question about tracing in a binary search in which we're meant to trace variables x and y when applied to a string array.

I've attached an image of the question below:

[image]

I am able to fill in the line, target, x, y and m values correctly, however, do not understand how the comp values are determined.

A sample solution is shown in the image below for "George".

[image]

I would highly appreciate if someone could explain how the comp values are calculated.

Thanks

Comment: String.compareTo just compares 2 Strings lexicographically. Important part is that result could be positive, zero, or negative. Concrete values (+5, -3 etc) aren't important. For more details you can look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Take the example of a phone book. In a phone book, the names are listed in alphabetical order. What binary search does is that it goes straight into the middle page of the phone book and see if the value if there or not, if the value that you want is "less than" the value in the phone book,(alphabetically) you go to the right half of the phone book and look at the middle page of that side. if the value that you want is "greater than" the value in the phone book, you go to the left half of the phone book and look at the middle page of that side. Then, when the value you want is finally equal to the value on the page, you return the page number.

In the example code, low can be represented by the first page in a phone book. The high can be represented by the last page in a phone book. You want to find the value "target" and a String[] array named "a" is given. This array can be represented by the phone book itself. What you want to do is compare your "target" string using the binary search algorithm outlined above and find the index where the "target" string matches the string in the array. The String.compareTo(anotherString) method is necessary in this case because the method takes a String and compares it to anotherString, returning a number. If that number is negative, the String is earlier in the alphabet than anotherString. If that number is positive, the String is later in the alphabet than anotherString. If that number is equal, then the two strings are completely identical, therefore returns a zero.

Hope this helps!